# For each element in array-json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

1) What I want is to have:

```
element1 = [roof, walls, floor]
element2 = [table, chair]
```

2) My starting point is:

```
for(var i=0;i<roomElements;i++){ 
var room = [];
room.push({"element" + i + : getElement(room)});
}
```

"i" ruins the party. How can I append a dynamic variable to my json array?

I need room to be an object like:

```
   var room = {"element1":"roof,walls,floor","element2":"table,chair"};
```

And then I want to process that object -somehow- so I can get:

```
element1 = [roof, walls, floor]
element2 = [table, chair]
```

And then I want to echo these new variables with something like.

```
  for each element in room
```

So I can output:

```
  alert("element 1 has roof, walls,floor", "element2 has table, chair")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (before ES6) use dynamic field names like that.

Instead of `room.push({"element" + i + : getElement(room)});`, you would need:

```
var foo = {};
foo["element" + i] = getElement(room);
room.push(foo);
```

With ES6, you can use calculated property name, so

```
room.push({["element" + i]: getElement(room)});
```

becomes legal.

Because you're reinitializing `elem` each iteration, that still won't do exactly what you wanted. It would probably work better to take each of your starting arrays, [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) their elements, and create a finished object of the results:

```
var json = {
  element1: element1.join(','),
  element2: element2.join(',')
};
```

Comment: With your first solution variable 'foo' becomes this : [element1:roof,walls,floor, [Circular] ] ]. I don't know what it means. How can I print each foo, or each element?